# Get Shell TabBar height from iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to be able to set a static property in my App.cs with the TabBar height on iOS. I think I probably need a custom renderer to achieve this,

This would be trivial if it were just a TabbedPage - but with Shell I can not see a way to access and store what I need.

Has anyone done anything similar and will to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ignore - re read the documentation and found the answer! Can override CreateShellItemRenderer!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers